# Understanding standard deviation equivalent with percentile

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

I don't have a great understanding in statistics, but I have to answer an MCQ featuring the following question :

My individual has a height situated at -3SD (Standard deviation) and the following assertions are true :

- The individual is situated in the first percentile
- There is a height where the individual is in the 0.5% of the population

When I look at wikipedia page ([See this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#/media/File:Standard_deviation_diagram.svg)) it's pretty clear why the individual is in the first percentile.

However I don't understand why the second assertion is true. Is it an error ? What am I missing ?

Comment: This depends on what distribution you are referring to.  If it is a normal distribution you can determine exactly what proportion of the distribution is  in the lower left tail. It would be approximately .0013

Comment: This is below the lower 1% and is also less than 0.5%.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I have a normal distribution. @MichaelChernick do you mean that -3DS is at the same time below 1% and 0,5% ? Is it something that you're supposed to know or can it be demonstrated ?

Comment: The normal distribution is determined by its mean and variance.  So you can convert it to a standard normal and compute the integral from -$\infinity$ to -3 and this is only 0.0013 which is 0.13%.  It can be found in common statistical tables.